# Group of Jacobians of on $C^\infty$ real manifold.

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, jacobian

$M$ is an $n$-dimensional $C^\infty$ Hausdorff and path-connected manifold. Let's employ some atlas for it.

Let $p$ be some point on this manifold.

Various charts containing the point p exist. Choose some "reference chart" for the time being.

For any other chart containing $p$, one obtains a Jacobian operator of the second chart, with respect to the reference chart, at $p$.

The ability to switch between many different coordinate systems allows one to define composition between Jacobians - from where it's realized that they should form a group (not hard to prove).

You'd get groups for each reference coordinate system at the point $p$. These groups should be isomorphic (not hard to prove), so this group is definable on the tangent space itself.

For instance, this group should be $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ for the maximal atlas.

For various choices of atlases,you'd get various groups (because these groups are always definable). Call this the Jacobian group at the poin $p$, $\mathcal{J}_p$.

For each point, take the homomorphism $\mathrm{det}$from this "Jacobian group" to its determinant in $\mathbb{R}$. This will be a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. I'll call this the group $\mathrm{Det}_{p}$, for the point $p$. The determinant groups for different points may well be different (examples galore of this).

Here's a question: is there some "nice criterion" that I can employ to shrink my atlas, suitably enough, so that the resulting "determinant groups for each point" reveal properties of the manifold?

I'm expecting that I could get some information on the orientability of the manifold, were I to do this.

Disclaimer: I come from a physics background, so I'm not sure if everything's well-defined. Feel free to point out, and I'll suitably modify the question to make it properly defined.

Comment: well, it's not exactly a pointwise thing, but if you can find an atlas for the manifold such that for any two charts in that atlas, the transition maps have positive Jacobian determinant, then the manifold is orientable (this is even one of the possible definitions of orientability). For some manifolds, this is just not possible, so we call those manifolds non-orientable (the Mobius strip being the standard example)

Comment: This sounds not unlike a [sheaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)).

Comment: Are you looking for reduction of structure group, or equivalently [$G$-structure on a manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-structure_on_a_manifold)?

Comment: This is very similar to the notion of a [frame bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle). Rather than using coordinate charts, you can use local frames, which are local vector fields that form a basis at each tangent space. This gives you a [principal $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle) whose principal subbundles provide a unified way of encoding various geometric structures on $M$. This perspective is ubiquitous in modern differential geometry (as well as some fields of physics).

Comment: @Kajelad, yes, there sounds like an overlap between the concept I'm defining upstairs and what you just mentioned. Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: My motivation to ask this question is to see if there are pathways to get a better intrinsic or intuitive "feel" for various concepts of differential geometry using less elaborate machinery (like going to frame bundles, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that if $G \leq {\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ is a subgroup, then an atlas $\mathfrak{A} =\{(U_\alpha, \varphi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a $G$-atlas if for all $\alpha,\beta \in A$ with $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \neq \varnothing$, the Jacobian ${\rm d}(\varphi_\alpha \circ \varphi_\beta^{-1})_x$ is in $G$, for all $x \in \varphi_\beta[U_\alpha \cap U_\beta]$.

Since transition maps for any atlas are diffeomorphisms, every atlas is a ${\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)$-atlas. So the interesting question is: when can we find an atlas with a smaller $G$?

- the manifold is orientable if and only if it admits a ${\rm GL}_n^+(\Bbb R)$-atlas. This is also equivalent to finding an ${\rm SL}_n(\Bbb R)$-atlas.
- the manifold admits a flat Riemannian metric if and only if it admits an ${\rm O}(n)$-atlas.
- if $n = 2k$, the manifold has a complex structure if and only if it admits a ${\rm GL}_k(\Bbb C)$-atlas (there's a canonical embedding ${\rm GL}_k(\Bbb C)\hookrightarrow {\rm GL}_{2k}(\Bbb R)$).
- if $n=2k$, the manifold admits a symplectic structure if and only if it admits a ${\rm Sp}_{2k}(\Bbb R)$-atlas.

Can you see where I'm getting at? The keyword here is "$G$-structure". Here, we're talking about integrable $G$-structures, which correspond to $G$-atlases. More generally, a $G$-structure on $M$ is a principal $G$-subbundle of the frame bundle of $M$, whose fibers are $G$-orbits of the right action of $G$ on the frame bundle (namely, the restriction of the ${\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)$-action given by change of bases). The core idea here is that, for example, defining a Riemannian metric on the manifold is the same thing as (consistently) prescribing which bases of all tangent spaces will be orthonormal. Similar reasoning for other geometric structures.

See [Marius Crainic's notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Ecrain101/DG-2015/main10.pdf) for more on the subject.

Comment: The correspondence between $O(n)$ and metrics, etc. is valid at the level of frames, but not at the level of coordinate charts (at least in the Riemannian case). Even if the manifold has a metric, it will not generally be possible to choose the atlas whose charts have $O(n)$ transition functions, since the coordinate frames need not (and, in some cases, cannot) be orthonormal.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it seems that the "group property" of these Jacobian transformations themselves may not be all that interesting. But the fact there are "suitably chosen atlases" for which Jacobians always are members of certain groups - that point is interesting.

Comment: Oops. Kajelad is right, that's what I get for writing an answer half-asleep. What I wrote is true for flat metrics, let me fix it.